# Why do built in exception messages tend to not have specific details? (e.g. key from a dictionary)

Tags: c#, .net, exception

I'm sure I've seen this in various exception messages in the framework.  I checked the following pages from the MSDN library but could not find much guidance for the message contents:

[Exception Throwing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229030%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
[Error Message Design](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229056%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
[Exception.Message Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.message.aspx)

The only part in the first page that could explain it is this text:

> Do not disclose security-sensitive information in exception messages
>   without demanding appropriate permissions.

It's the the ArgumentException thrown by [Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.Add method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7z0zy8k.aspx) that reminded me of this issue.  It looks like this:

```
System.ArgumentException : An item with the same key has already been added.
```

Why does it not look something like this?

```
System.ArgumentException : An item with the same key(123) has already been added.
```

This assumes 123 is the TKey value, basically any format with the TKey value is what I would thing would be useful to track down an error while debugging.

Is there a known reason why this is not included?

Would it be considered bad practice to re-thrown the argument exception with the key in the message?  I had considered making my own exception subclass but I think this is a case where using a built in exception class seems like a better option.

Comment: Perhaps for localization reasons

Comment: That could make sense.  Because the TKey could be of various types they take the common case that can always apply, basically a fixed message.

Comment: I think because `Dictionary` is general-purpose and the key might contain security-sensitive information. If you know exactly that your key is not security-sensitive, so it should be fine to add it to the exception's message.

Comment: Just Debug.log the key somewhere before you call the Add method. Or wrap the dictionary in a class and implement an add method with a custom exception.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, exceptional situations in frameworks want to avoid creating *new* exceptional situations. To format the message like this:

```
System.ArgumentException : An item with the same key(123) has already been added.
```

One would have to assume there is a valid implementation of `toString` on the key parameter. But what if it is `null`? Or if it is a custom key that throws a new exception in its `toString`? Or even some idiot implemented a `toString` method that throws a random exception 1 out of 10 times? What if the internal exception  was caused by an out of memory situation and the conversion would just trigger it again? It would give more unpredictable results than just reporting what it is **sure** to be able to report.

Comment: These objections are all solvable. Nulls can be turned into some string like `null`, and exception handling can be wrapped around the string conversion, producing an alternative string expansion in the case that an exception bubbles out.

Comment: @EuroMicelli I'm with the OP and Kaz, the most common scenarios uses primitive types

Comment: @Kaz: Of course they're solvable. At a cost. The question is not whether the problem is solvable, the question is whether spending the money is a good way to spend the budget vs spending it on a feature that helps more people.

Comment: @Kaz: But if the `ToString` has a bug that results in `OutOfMemoryException` or `StackOverflowException`, which can't be caught, attempting to add a duplicate key will crash the program.

Comment: If objects are being put in a dictionary, and their `toString` has a horrible bug, it will be an unfortunate set of circumstances that this bug is first discovered during a duplicate key insertion.  Both issues have to be fixed; the solution isn't "don't ever use `toString` because it might be buggy.

Comment: @Kaz that's completely beside the point and not what I or anyone else is saying. We're saying that a good, stable and reliable framework does not use something that ***might*** be buggy, or cause its own exceptions, in a light-weight exception handler. If you want more info - catch the base exception and rethrow with more information. The framework should **not** impose the risks and this performance penalty **by default**.

Comment: So for instance, a user-supplied comparison method might be buggy, so the framework should choose its own bug-free way to compare objects for the sake of inserting them into the dictionary.

Comment: It doesn't sort within exception handlers usually. The whole point is that it shouldn't do risky (or potentially compromising) stuff *within the light-weight default exceptions*. Again: if you *want* to disclose more info, catch it and *rethrow* with more info. You can take all the risks you want in *your* own handlers.

Answer (score 8):

It looks like a security precaution. The program could be working with security-sensitive data, which it takes care not to write into log messages or reveal through the UI. But, oops, there is a problem and an unhandled exception goes off, where some default handler displays or logs pieces of that sensitive information because it was included in the exception text.